# Chronometer is reset on when the app configuration changes in Android

Tags: java, android, android-viewmodel, chronometer

I am created a Stopwatch app with using `Chronometer` and ViewModel the app is working well until the configuration change. when the rotation of the screen the Stopwatch is reset into `00:00`.

> this is part of `StopwatchTabFrag.java`.

```java
stopwatchTabViewModel.buttonIcon.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer imgId) {

                switch (imgId){
                    //when the icon is changed to pause (or) when user clicks play icon then Stopwatch is start.
                    case R.drawable.ic_round_pause_circle_filled_24:
                        binding.stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        binding.startPause.setImageResource(imgId);
                        stopwatchTabViewModel.startStopwatch(stopwatchChronometer);
                        break;
                    //when the icon is changed to start (or) when user clicks pause icon then Stopwatch is pause.
                    case R.drawable.ic_round_play_arrow_24:
                        binding.startPause.setImageResource(imgId);
                        stopwatchTabViewModel.pauseStopwatch(stopwatchChronometer);
                        break;
                    case R.drawable.ic_round_stop_24:
                        binding.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        stopwatchTabViewModel.stopStopwatch(stopwatchChronometer);
                }
            }
        });
```

I am using Observer to whenever changing the particular button icon it was execute this particular task.

> this is part of `StopwatchTabViewModel.java`.

```java
public void startStopwatch(Chronometer chronometer){
        if (!isRunning.getValue()){
            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-pauseOfset.getValue());
            chronometer.start();
            _isRunning.setValue(true);
        }
    }

    public void pauseStopwatch(Chronometer chronometer){
        if (isRunning.getValue()){
            chronometer.stop();
            _pauseOfset.setValue(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-chronometer.getBase());
            _isRunning.setValue(false);
        }
    }

    public void stopStopwatch(Chronometer chronometer){
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        _pauseOfset.setValue(0L);
        chronometer.stop();

        //Reset the icon to Start
        _buttonIcon.setValue(R.drawable.ic_round_play_arrow_24);
    }
```

I implemented the Stopwatch task methods in `ViewModel` class. I don't know if this is correct or wrong.

**I am waiting for your answers.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line to your `Activity`s declaration in manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
```

it will prevent `Activity` destroy on rotation (thus also your chrono), you have to handle rotation in `onConfigurationChanged` method call by yourself (you probably won't need to do anything in your case)

[HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes) you have some info about configuration changing.